# Conference participation request for myself or for the entire team

Tags: team, conferences, off-site-events

In a couple of weeks there's going to be a conference closely related to my field of work. In one of the previous talks I had with my managed he said that if I find something that I consider interesting I should let him know and he said he'll try and send me there.

Now here's my problem. I'm part of a small team of 3 and I'm pretty sure that all of us are interested and would love a chance to go.

- Do I talk with my teammates and we send a group mail?
- Do I tell the others and we all spam the manager one by one?
- Do I send the email and mention that the other might also be interested?
- Do I send an email just for me?

Any other option would also be welcomed.
My goal here is to preferably go to the conference but more important not be an asshole to my teammates.

Comment: You are assuming that your team would be interested too. And Manager spoke only to you, why to pull up the whole team? If manager can/want/have to, he would have spoken to all (and maybe he did one-to-one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other option is to ask your manager yourself.

> This conference that you said I could go to.  This would also be of interest to my team mates.  Could we arrange to all go as a group?

The chances are that there's only budget for you to go, or that work will back up if everyone goes at once - it's your manager's call.

Comment: +1, though using 'benefit' instead of 'interest' might work better? That suggests that the business would get something in return then (experience or knowledge), rather than just satisfying an interest and going on a jolly

Comment: Even that OP is "_pretty sure_", this is still based on OP's assumption  that his mates would be interested too. What if they were not? So I think OP should speak of himself only, since manager spoke to him only.

Answer (score 1):

In previous companies where I worked there were 40+ people conferences were interesting for. The company couldn't send all 40 of them there, as I doubt your manager will be happy to be without a team for a day (or more?), but that depends on the manager/company.

Tell your manager you'd like to go (and ask about going as a team) and inform your teammates about the conference.

In case he can't send all three of you, make a summary of most important points and share the information with your teammates.